# ETL How to read XML on website to load in my local DB

Tags: xamarin, etl

I hope you all are fine, well, I really do not have the ability to use ETL is my first attempt :) and I need to read an XML document on the website to load my local SQL DB servers: /

An example or document is this [XML](http://www.goalserve.com/samples/soccer_odds.xml)

Basically in this example it is for only one, but later I will need several XML files of different API's

Could be so kind to help me understand how the process would be: /

I do not know whether to do a database first or ETL allows me to create the DB from the XML tags. Have resources that they can share to better understand the process I need.

Comment: The approach depends a lot on your technology stack.  What DB are you using?  SQLite?  What platform and language are you using for the import?  C# in a Xamarin app?

Comment: Well, My local db is SQl Servers 2014 and i post the result in asp.net using C#